# Transparency in stacked imagemosaics coverages

Tags: raster, geoserver, sld, transparency-opacity, image-mosaic

I'm using geoserver to stack several raster images that have different ELEVATION parameter (each ELEVATION "number" is a different layer so to speak).

This raster images are 16-bit one channel Geotiffs, from which i make a false color image in geoserver with this SLD:

```
        <ColorMap>
          <ColorMapEntry color="#FFFFFF" quantity="0" opacity="0"/>
          <ColorMapEntry color="#000000" quantity="1" opacity="1"/>
          ... other irrelevant entries ...
          <ColorMapEntry color="#FF00FF" quantity="65534" opacity="1"/>
          <ColorMapEntry color="#FFFFFF" quantity="65535" opacity="0"/>
        </ColorMap>
```

As you can see, I'm creating a transparency from values 0 and 65535 in the original raster data.

The problem arises when I stack several elevations, where transparencies are not rendered correctly, and do not show data on lower layers (elevations):

[image: Transparencies do not show data of other lower elevations]

I've tried to set input transparency to #FFFFFF, but it won't work as it is a 16 bit image. And tried MergeBehavior FLAT and STACK, with no success.

Comment: can you clarify where the issue is in your image, several of your images seem to have transparency and lower tiles showing through

Comment: How are you stacking the various elevations? Can you show us a request?

Comment: hi @IanTurton, yes of course: there should be visible data (the green-orange layers) inside every black polygon. Each polygon is a different layer, stacked with geoserver. The problem is that upper layers are creating a transparent "void" in lower layers where they should be data. This void is generated by no-data pixels in upper layers that seem to be considered transparent after the image stacking is made and not before.

Comment: Hi @AndreaAime, thanks for your feedback, y stacking them querying for a list of elevations, for example: .../wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.0&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image/png&TRANSPARENT=true&TILED=true&LAYERS=test:ndvi1&ELEVATION=172,173,174,94,195,196,197,198&TIME=2017-11-11T00:00:00Z&WIDTH=256&HEIGHT=256&SRS=EPSG:3857&STYLES=&BBOX=-6993070.843754206,-4189972.1424802206,-6990624.85884908,-4187526.157575095

Answer (score 1):

Querying a list of elevations implies that the image mosaic will do the mosaicking in the original color/sample model, and only after that the colormap will activate on the result.

To achieve what you want I believe you'll have to use separate WMS requests and stack on the client side.

Comment: Oh, i was trying to avoid that, as having multiple layers client side is a mess. I noticed that with RGB images that have an alpha channel this works fine. But i guess i cant add an alpha channel to a single channel 16 bit image.